# Sizing heat exchanger for cooling humidified hydrogen

Tags: heat-transfer, cooling, gas

I have a chemical reactor producing a humidified stream of hydrogen gas and I need to cool it down to near ambient temperature using a heat exchanger, say 25 degrees Celsius.

Within the reactor I measure a gas temperature of 70 degrees Celsius and 100% relative humidity. In the lab I measure a gas flow rate of 10 liters per minute using a calibrated mass flow controller after the gas passes through a jacketed reflux condenser, a water trap, and a tube of silica desiccant. Between the mass flow controller and the silica gel I measure a temperature close to ambient and a relative humidity of 40%.

How would I size an off-the-shelf air cooled heat exchanger to create the same level of gas cooling as the reflux condenser? The silica gel is only there to protect the mass flow controller, I would be okay with 95% relative humidity hydrogen as long as the temperature is near ambient.

In my mind I think I could purchase any small, cheap air cooled heat exchanger off Amazon but I'd rather try to approach the problem analytically. I plan on having a water trap after the heat exchanger to catch the condensed water vapor.

Comment: Please edit this block of text - some formatting would probably let others read it.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with calculating required heat flux for cooling down your stream, then you can use online calculator, for example [this](https://checalc.com/calc/AirExch.html). Keep in mind 2 things:

- If you expect condensation as the stream cools down, this may impede
  function of the air cooler, so you may need to use a condenser
  instead.
- Trying to go with the stream temperature near ambient might be
  difficult, if your cooling fluid is the ambient air.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Could you elaborate on how to calculate the heat flux? A link to a tutorial would be fine if you know any simple ones. And what would be the difference between a heat and a condenser?

Comment: @DallonPenney "Heat flux" is the process duty as one of the basic input parameters [here](https://cheguide.com/air_cooled_exch.html). You can calculate it from cooled stream enthalpy difference between outlet and inlet multiplied by flowrate.